# Websites typically use popup windows to implement OAuth. How can we handle this in flutter_inappwebview?

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-inappwebview

What I have come up with till now is to manually override methods like window.open, window.postMessage and window.onmessage to internally create a bridge within Dart.

Is there a standard approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on a [medium post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/inappwebview-the-real-power-of-webviews-in-flutter-c6d52374209d#b910) under the heading: How to manage popup windows opened with target=”_blank” or “window.open”.

The key is to implement the onCreateWindow method and create another InAppWebView instance with the windowId received from CreateWindowAction.

Answer (score 0):

Most API providers prohibit the use of webviews for Oauth because of security concerns. Providers require the use of an external browser to execute authorization of username and password. With Android, you must register a Callback activity in your manifest for the provider to direct the user to after authorization is complete and the browser closes.

You can look at [oauth2_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2_client) to see how the author of that library handled the callback and how to configure it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! In my case, since I'm building a "browser" that opens third party websites, the authentication flow (which has typically been developed using popup windows) is not under my control.
I was able to solve using https://stackoverflow.com/a/68337208/2476004 and modifying the UserAgent of the web view.